# requests & urllib failed get complete html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I was trying to get the comments & authors. The authors are chained so that I know who was replying to who. So it is important to store all comments out there otherwise replies to the missing comment are nowhere to be chained. (I know it is kinda confusing, but on this website, replies are also comments but special that also indicates the author of the comment they reply to.)

From a Chinese website (https://www.zhihu.com/node/AnswerCommentListV2?params=%7B%22answer_id%22%3A%2215184366%22%7D) using requests.

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent,
           }
url = "https://www.zhihu.com/node/AnswerCommentListV2?params=%7B%22answer_id%22%3A%"+"2215184366"+"%22%7D"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects = True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
soup.prettify()
for comment in soup.find_all("div", "zm-item-comment"):
    p = comment.find("a", "zg-link author-link")
    print(p)
```

However, I found that the codes above can get me most of the content I want but with some "holes". Most of the comments are nicely listed but some are missing. During the debug, **I found that the response from requests was incomplete. The response itself missed some comments for unknown reasons.**
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK1h6.png)(where all "None" should be comments)

I also tried similar approach using urllib and no good.

Could you please help me get the complete html as the browser does?

Update: 
I think the problem has to do with the response from the website. The simple requests.get cannot get the full website as Chrome does. I am wondering if a fundamental solution to get the complete html exists.
I have tried @eLRuLL's code. It does get the lost authors name. However, the lost authors all appear to be "知乎用户” which means the general user of that website. (I am expecting different and specific user names) Comparing to the Chrome browser, the browser displays specific user names well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You will have all the authors and comments.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.zhihu.com/node/AnswerCommentListV2?params=%7B%22answer_id%22%3A%"+"2215184366"+"%22%7D"
res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select(".zm-item-comment"):
    try:
        author = item.select(".author-link")[0].text
        comment = item.select(".zm-comment-content")[0].text
        print(author,comment)
    except:pass
```

Comment: Thank you. It does get me all available comments & authors and filters out all missing parts. Do you happen to know how to get the full response from the website?

Comment: @Yi Shen, perhaps you are new to SO. When you get useful answer to your erected question, you are supposed to mark that as your answer. This is how it works. As for the answer to your additional question: if the very site you are talking about are not within javascript encrypted then there is nothing wrong with your usual process to get the full content. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you think that all the comments should be inside an `a` tag, but if you check, the comments you are missing are exactly the ones that don't have a link on the user's name (so you can't use `a` tag to find them), so to get the name of the author you'd have to use:

```
p = comment_author.find("div", "zm-comment-hd").text
print(p)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is a very good work around. 
However, when I check the html on Chrome, each comment does have a "a tag".

Comment: I think you are confusing the comment with the author, you showed the example of the author. Some of them don't have a link, check the one after `vivian`

Comment: Strange!!!! When I used your codes, it does show every author of the comments. However, for those "originally missing authors", they appear to be "知乎用户“ which refers to the general the user of that website （They shouldn't be, I am expecting a specific user name like Mike)

Comment: that's a problem with the website. I don't know the language, so I am just pointing to the position "I think" the author should be, and it gets it.